# Canvas size in pixels (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, canvas

[image]I am creating an application for web browsers. The user clicks on a position of the screen. The position is stored with the x-value and y-value in pixels.

Now I would like to draw a rectangle on a canvas with this method:
ctx.rect(x,x,50,50);
Unfortunately these values do not fit to the pixels in a web browser.

Do you know how I could change the pixel in a webbrowser to create a rect at the right position?

Comment: what do you mean with change the pixel? Do you want to increase the size of the canvas?

Comment: I added an image. The value 80 for the canvas rectangle are not 80px of the screen. Hope that you understand it.

Comment: What's the resolution of your screen? It might be hiDPI which will mean that your screen uses scaling and 1 physical pixel doesn't equal 1 logical pixel.

Comment: 1366x768 Pixels, how can I convert the pixel formats?

Comment: try `window.devicePixelRatio` in your developer console, if it gives a value different from 1 then your screen pixels are not exactly 1 physical pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your canvas size have to match his style size.

for ex. if your canvas is 100px x 100px you must have

```
myCanvas.width = 100
myCanvas.height= 100
myCanvas.style.width = '100px'
myCanvas.style.height = '100px'
```

only in this case *"your canvas bits size will match the screen bits size"*

Comment: Great answer. This is the solution. Thank you so much.